# Is there any Xcode plug-in for code review?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any Xcode plug-in for code review?

Comment: Xcode supports plug-ins in theory, however I've never seen any implemented/available for download....

Comment: is there any API for Xcode plugin development? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to find one. The new versions of Xcode (at least to 4.4) do not support plugins, so the sort of thing you are looking for isn't going to be available.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.reviewboard.org/

Here is a decent free and open solution. You may not like all the features but it should give you everything you need for a solid web-based review tool.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: but i need a tool integrated in Xcode